# How does 'this' keyword work in map() and call()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, this, call

I have been refreshing my JavaScript knowledge of `call()` and `map()` usage on `NodeList`.

It was fairly easy to google out, what `call()` should be doing and there are resources with examples of how it works with `map()`.

However, as I noticed on MDN, the `map()` function can also take a second argument, which should be setting the `this` keyword for `map()` - or at least that is what I think it should be doing.

I have tried to check it myself with simple arrays:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

..and with a simple function, that is about to be given as a parameter to `map()`:

```
var effector = function (x) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

Now, what I do not understand, is why these two function calls have different results:

```
numbers.map(effector, letters);
numbers.map.call(letters, effector);
```

I expect them to both output letters to the console, as both `this` keywords should be referencing to them (respectively to their objects).

I did some further research, and tried with this modified effector function:

```
var effector = function () {
    console.log(this);
}
```

..again on:

```
numbers.map(effector, letters);
numbers.map.call(letters, effector);
```

Assuming, that we are in "use strict", the first call logs `letters` and the second logs `undefined`.

But again, I would expect both these calls to produce the same output.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I was reading, how `.map` can be polyfilled, if you check it on MDN, there you see, how the second parameter of .map is used in `callback.call()`.

I suppose, that in the end, even that `callback.call()` should have the same `this` as was in `.map`.

[MDN - map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I expect them to have the same results, without any possible difference. I should highlight it in the post though.

Comment: side note: you can also change `this` with the `.bind()` method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two bindings of the `this` reference at play here:

- `this` for the execution context of the `map` function
- `this` for the execution context of the callback function

They don't relate to each other.

The second argument of `map` dictates what `this` will be for the callback. If it is not provided, the default is `undefined` (not the array).

The first argument of `map.call` dictates what `this` will be for `map` -- and by consequence which array will be iterated.

This is also reflected in the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) provided on mdn: it is perfectly in line with these specifications: `O` gets the value of `this` for the `map` function, and `T` gets the value of `this` for the callback. They are generally different.

### `map` versus `forEach`

Unrelated to your question, but worth mentioning: don't use `map` when you are not actually *mapping* anything. `map` is intended for creating a new array, one in which every value has been mapped by calling the callback function on the original value at that same index.

When however you just need to iterate the array values, without any intent to perform such mapping, then use the `forEach` method, or a `for...of` loop. Both these work on `NodeList` out of the box, without the need to `.call`.

Comment: You got there about a minute before me :) (and expressed it much more clearly that I did)

Comment: Thanks for trying to clarify map use and to answers my question, but could you please check my edit? I probably understand your answer, but I think, that there is something more.

I know about return value of .map, I was focused on it, because soon I will start with learning React and I know, that map is used for JSX returns, not like forEach. And I didnt want to change my question to forEach, as I wanted to avoid possible new challanges from map/forEach differences.

Comment: I read your edit, but I see nothing in the polyfill that is not in line with my answer. The variable `T` is undefined, unless `map` received a second argument: in that case `T` becomes that value. `T` will be the `this` value for the callback (only). This is what I am saying in my answer: that `this` has nothing to do with the `this` with which `map` itself is called.

Comment: The last statement you just added to your question is false: they are not the same `this`. It is the core message of my answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks. '(not the array)' statement helped me to understand it.

I marked your answer as correct.

Also thanks for patience, I deleted the wrong statement.

I realize, that second argument of `.map` was just a local variable, while `this` was referencing to the 'parent' object (array) of `.map` method. (could you maybe integrate that 'local variable' explanation in your answer? If you agree, that it might help to some not so experienced programmers?)

Is there even a practical use of second argument of .map?

Comment: The practical use is completely up to the programmer: it is a convenience that is offered. It can be of use when such a `map` is called within a class method, where you want the callback to have `this` referring to that class instance, so it can call other methods of the class with `this.method` notation.

Comment: Note that *all* arguments of a function are local variables in that function. It is a general principle.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `numbers.map(effector, letters)` and `numbers.map.call(letters, effector)` lies in *which function* the `this` is set to `letters`.

In the first, as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) explains, the second argument is the value to use as `this` inside the callback - ie the argument supplied to `map`. That is, in `numbers.map(effector, letters)`, the `this` inside `effector` will be `letters`. Since `effector` (in the first version) doesn't care what `this` is, that argument essentially has no effect, and the contents of `numbers` are logged.

In `numbers.map.call(letters, effector)`, on the other hand, it is `numbers.map` that has its `this` set to `letters`. Which effectively means the `map` method, although called on `numbers`, is "hijacked" into logging the entries of `letters` instead.

The second example works similarly - the crucial thing is *which* function the `this` is set in: `effector` in one case, `numbers.map` in the other.

Comment: I gave you upvote, so even though you will not be shown above the previous answer, you can earn some reputation.

As I commented in the previous answer, there may be something more unclear with using map, could you please check 'EDIT' at the end of my question?